# Is there a way to remove part of a file name (path) in python?

Tags: python

I have around 50 files that have their name and then the date they were created at 3 times. How can I remove that part from the file name in python (You can show an example with other data it doesn't really matter)

I tried something like that:

```
file = 'directory/imagehellohellohello.png'
keyword = 'hello'

if (file.count(keyword) >= 3):
    //functionality (here I want to remove the hello's from the file path)
```

Comment: Look into the `os` module, this is quite a frequent task.

Comment: yeah i know how to use it (give or take) but i can't get that to work.

Comment: Then please edit your question and show the code you're having problems with.

Comment: kindly show your approach to solve it so that we can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("directory/imagehellohellohello.png")
target = path.with_name(path.name.replace("hello", ''))

path.rename(target)
```

And this indeed renames the file to `"directory/image.png"`.

- From Python version 3.8 the `rename` method also returns the new files' path as a `Path` object. (So it is possible to do:

  ```
  target = path.rename(path.with_name(path.name.replace("hello", '')))
  ```

---

Methods/attributes used: [`Path.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename), [`Path.with_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name), [`Path.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name), [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = 'directory/imagehellohellohello.png'
keyword = 'hello'
if keyword*3 in file:
   newname = file.replace(keyword*3, '')
   os.rename(file, newname)
```